# How to draw scatter diagram according to {month, day} time format

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I want to plot in the {Month,Day} time format, but the `DateListPlot` function seems to only accept the {Year, Month, Day} format. What can I do to draw the time image correctly?

```
data={{{1, 20}, 269.`}, {{1, 21}, 403.`}, {{1, 22}, 523.`}, {{1, 23}, 
  783.`}, {{1, 24}, 1183.`}, {{1, 25}, 1796.`}, {{1, 26}, 
  2528.`}, {{1, 27}, 4172.`}, {{1, 28}, 6496.`}, {{1, 29}, 
  8531.`}, {{1, 30}, 10642.`}, {{1, 31}, 12978.`}, {{2, 1}, 
  15232.`}, {{2, 2}, 17697.`}, {{2, 3}, 20522.`}, {{2, 4}, 
  23614.`}, {{2, 5}, 27426.`}, {{2, 6}, 31029.`}, {{2, 7}, 
  34038.`}, {{2, 8}, 37346.`}, {{2, 9}, 42508.`}, {{2, 10}, 
  45767.`}, {{2, 11}, 47609.`}, {{2, 12}, 49082.`}, {{2, 13}, 
  62170.`}}
DateListPlot[%]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option [`DateFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateFunction.html)

```
DateListPlot[data, DateFunction :> (Prepend[#, 2020] &)]
```

or prepend the `{month, day}` pairs with an arbitrary year:

```
DateListPlot[MapAt[Prepend[#, 2020] &, data, {All, 1}]]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or another variant:

```
DateListPlot[ReplacePart[#, 1 -> Prepend[#[[1]], 2020]] & /@ data]
```